# Cannot switch activities in my android app, getting java.lang.NullPointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My app has two activities and one java file extending ArrayAdapter.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.prajjwal.myfreight_0;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final String[] comptype ={"Exporter","Shipper","Freight Forwarder","Custom House Agent","Transporter"};
String ss;
TextView tv1,tv2;
RadioGroup rg1;
RadioButton rb1;
Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    rg1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int selid=rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); 
            rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(selid);
            ss="did";

            if(rb1.getText().toString().equals(comptype[0])) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FreeActivity.class);
                i1.putExtra("did", comptype[0]);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        }
    });



}
```

FreeActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FreeActivity extends Activity {

ListView lw;
final String[] fields={"Name","User Name","E-mail","Company","Company E-mail"};
LoginListView llv1;
String s;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exp);
    Intent i1;
    i1=getIntent();
    s=i1.getStringExtra("did");

    llv1=new LoginListView(this,fields);
    lw.setAdapter(llv1);


}
```

LoginListView helper class

```
package com.prajjwal.myfreight_0;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginListView extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity a1;
private final String[] s1;

public LoginListView(Activity a, String[] s){
    super(a,R.layout.loginlist,s);
    s1=s;
    a1=a;
}

public View getView(int i,View v,ViewGroup vg) {
    LayoutInflater li=a1.getLayoutInflater();
    View v1=li.inflate(R.layout.loginlist, null, true);
    TextView tv;
    tv=(TextView)v1.findViewById(R.id.textView0);
    tv.setText(s1[i]);
    return v1;
    }

    }
```

loginlist.xml has a TableLayout with one TableRow containing a TextView and an EditText

activity_exp.xml has a ListView and an ImageView. I use the LoginListView class that extends ArrayAdapter to use in the listview. I get java.lang.NPE whenever I switch to FreeActivity.class. I can't seem to get what's wrong.

Comment: please post your error stack trace..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate your ListView before doing something with it. I'm pretty sure your LogCat tells you something about this.

```
public class FreeActivity extends Activity {

ListView lw;
final String[] fields={"Name","User Name","E-mail","Company","Company E-mail"};
LoginListView llv1;
String s;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exp);
    Intent i1;
    i1=getIntent();
    s=i1.getStringExtra("did");

    llv1=new LoginListView(this,fields);
    lw = new ListView(this);//add this
    lw.setAdapter(llv1);


}
```

Also, practice using a proper variable name for readability. Using meaningless letters will make it hard for you and also for us when trying to help you.